# Find and replace LIKE sql data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm tring to run a find and replace query on some sql data using Management Studio. I basically want to remove the word FREE from any content.

I tried running this query;

```
UPDATE    Table_1
SET              ContentDetails = REPLACE(ContentDetails, 'FREE', '')
WHERE     (ContentDetails LIKE '%FREE%')
```

But I get an error saying that data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a `text` column, you would need to use [`updatetext`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), which is painful, at best. However, you can cast `contentdetails` as a `varchar(max)`, and you'll be peachy.

```
update table_1
set contentdetails = replace(cast(contentdetails as varchar(max)), 'FREE', '')
where contentdetails like '%FREE%'
```

Moreover, I highly recommend that you look into converting that column from `text` to `varchar(max)`. It, along with `ntext` and `image`, is a currently [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) data type, which will be removed at some point in the future of SQL Server.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. We're looking at redeveloping the sites so that we can get rid of all of the bad design from previous developers. :)

Comment: Could this be modified just to find all instances within a particular table, rather than having to go through each column individually?

Comment: @Neil: Sorry, but no. I mean, you can create a script that will run through each column if you use `sp_executesql` and `sys.columns`, but there's no "replace everything in this database" command.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET    ContentDetails = REPLACE(CAST(ContentDetails as VARCHAR), 'FREE', '')
WHERE  (ContentDetails LIKE '%FREE%')
```

although it might cut the data off where the value is longer than what fits in a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated due to comment**

I think all you need to do is cast your ContentDetails field as a varchar with the length of the field i.e.

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET ContentDetails = REPLACE(CAST(ContentDetails as VARCHAR(100)), 'FREE', '')
WHERE ContentDetails LIKE '%FREE%'
```

Comment: The where condition is not futile, it will reduce the amount of updated rows, which can translate to a significant speed up

Comment: Ah ok never thought of it that way!

Comment: Thanks guys. Will this still work if the column is of type text?

(Not sure why it was done as a text type originally.)

Comment: Any idea of how much of a speed up you get?  Is it on the order of 10 percent?  Or is it on the order of twice as fast, or better?